# Android - Retrieve variables from 2 separate onTouchListeners

Tags: java, android

I currently have two different `onTouchListener` objects, each covering one side of the screen. I would like the user to touch both sides simultaneously, and I want to calculate the time difference between the two touches. So far, I have set up two `onTouchListener` objects, and defined the variables I need in each. However, I am having trouble finding the difference between the two variables, since they were used in different `onTouchListener` objects. This is what I have tried so far:

`.java` file

```
public class Prompt5 extends Activity {

    long presstimeL1;
    long presstimeR1;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt5);

            touchLayoutL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                    //More code..

                    //Set the value of the variable
                    presstimeL1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                return true;
                }
            });

            touchLayoutR.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                    //More code..

                    //Set the value of the variable
                    presstimeR1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                return true;
                }
            });

    //Somehow find the difference between presstimeL1 and presstimeR1
    //The code below does not work because both presstimeL1 and presstimeR1 are 0 in this case
    long difference = presstimeL1 - presstimeR1;
```

As shown, `touchLayoutL` covers the left side of the screen, `touchLayoutR` covers the right side of the screen, `presstimeL1` gets the system time from the left side of the screen, and `presstimeR1` gets the time from the right side of the screen.

So as you can see, my goal is to get the difference between two variables used in different `onTouchListener` objects.

Comment: Put `next.setText(String.valueOf(presstimeL1));` inside of your listener

Comment: actually he did.. this question really does not make sense

Comment: @blackbelt in the second code snippet but not the first which I think is what he is trying to get working. But I might be wrong as I agree it is confusing

Comment: So where do you invoke this next.setText(String.valueOf(presstimeL1)); ? It should be invoked somehow, after onTouch is called, otherwise the "next" will always show value of 0.

Comment: It's not working because it is in `onCreate()` so it only runs when the Activity is first created. Do it the second way then explain/post what isn't working about that way

Comment: It needs to go somewhere other than `onCreate()` then. Like I said, it will only run once there

Comment: if you invoke `next.setText` inside `onCreate`, but outside `onTouch`, then it is called only once when the Activity is created and `presstimeL1` is equal to 0, and never again, so the text is not refreshed

Comment: Where and why do you need it somewhere else?

Comment: I think you just need to create a new method, put `next.setText(String.valueOf(presstimeL1));` and other things you need to do inside, and invoke this new method from `onTouch`

Comment: Don't create a new duplicate post. Just fix this one up with correct code and explanation. Then we can delete obsolete comments and make it a good post